# Getting data- attributes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

A `<img />` element has a `data-id` attribute that I want to retrieve using jQuery. I believe the `.data()` function can do this.

```
$('.photo').get(0).data('id')
```

**Problem:** When I tried using `.data('id')` to retrieve the attribute, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'data'
```

Where did I go wrong?

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/KLG3R/

Comment: `$('#result').html($('.photo').data('id'));` works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like others said, your problem is the `.get(0)` which returns the HTML element itself, rather than a jquery object. To get a certain element, you use the `:eq` pseudo selector like:

http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/KLG3R/2/

```
$('#result').html( $('.photo:eq(0)').data('id') );
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `first()` to get the first element from your set of elements.  `$('.photo').first().data('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use data to a jquery object and get(0) will return the element.

```
$('#result').html( $('.photo').data('id') );
```

Check the below fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KLG3R/1/

Answer (score 0):

`$('.photo').get(0)` will return the `HTMLImageElement`, not the jQuery object, so it doesn't have a method `.data`.

You should just do with: `$('.photo').data('id')`

Answer (score 0):

use .attr() function. Like

```
$('#result').html( $('.photo').attr('data-id') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using jQuery `.get()` you need to use `.eq()` in this case. Also your using `.data()` which is used to store data on the dom. You need to be using `.attr()` which gives you access to the attributes of the element.

```
$(function () {
    var photos = $('.photo');
    $('#result').html(photos.eq(0).attr('data-id'));
});
```

This should be working for you now: http://jsfiddle.net/KLG3R/4/

Answer (score 0):

1. There are two types of an element. That is DOM object and jQuery object;
2. jQuery object has `data()` method, while DOM object like your `xx..get(0)` has no method `data();`
3. So, if you want to use `data()` method, you must ensure the object is jQuery object.